# Opencart links not https?

Tags: ssl, https, hyperlink, opencart

I have purchased an ssl certificate, I have enabled the SSL setting in the settings and I have changed both config files to go to https but when I visit http://bit.ly/TCkEBv the first page is https the rest are not. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the forum thread, this is not actually a bug just the way that the cart is set up - that is most pages are not set as HTTPS and will revert to HTTP once you click on a non HTTPS link

Comment: Jay you answered it perfectly, for a solution to this visit http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=88580&p=358196#p358196

I needed all pages to be https in order to pass a pci compliance. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old thread but considering the recent google SSL-everywhere indexing changes, i figured it was relevant. The following example will make OC use https in all links. You have to change 3 characters in system/library/url.php. They deleted this on the forums which is understandable, but we have ran it for a week of production traffic on mixed SSL multistores with no issues.

WARNING: Your mods may be different - run through them all in a test after enabling this...especially any redirect managers. Here is the tweak for 1.5.6:

Open store/system/library/url.php and find `$url = $this->url;` in an IF statement somewhere near line 18. Change it to `$url = $this->ssl;` and there ya go.

PS: Also there is a vastly untested method to send the https-preferred as a header using `$response->addHeader('Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000');` but i am unsure of best spot to put it besides index.php. Also, although it works in test, unsure of all-server implications. Header controller seems logical, but not all OC areas use header controller :). Experiment with best placement for that....just dont do it in the $url replicator even if it seems like it works.

Comment: That helped me in simple way after trying all set of modifications @dhaupin

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a Domain called example.org
Instead of changing the code, in Apache, you could do this...

In addition to your Domain-SSL.conf, you can copy that configuration to Domain.conf and edit it to use port 80 instead of 443

Then, add this line in the Server definitions at the top, right before DirectoryIndex...

```
Redirect / https://example.org
```

This will simply redirect every request back to the SSL configuration, adding the https:// in front of every link.  No code changes required to OC.

This has been working on my busy production server for several years without a single problem.